# Cardinality of polynomials

Tags: cardinals

Lets say the set A consists of all the polynomials. And C denote the cardinal of real numbers.
1.) is the card (A) less than or equal to c?
2.) is the card of range of any nonconstant          function from A = C?
3.) the range of any nonconstant function which can be expressed as a difference of two functions from A has card = C?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

1. A countably infinite union of sets of cardinality $C$ also has cardinality $C$
2. The set $\mathbb R^n$ has cardinality $C$, and so does any set with a bijecion to $\mathbb R^n$.
3. The set $A$ can be written as a countably infinite union of sets which, using point 2., can be shown to be of cardinality $C$.

Comment: Does it work the same also if the set of polynomials is changed to the set of differentiable functions or integrable functions?

Comment: @Jus It doesn't work the same way, no. The same argument cannot be made. But I suggest you ask a new question for that.